# Finding the most recent record in a table matching a specific condition

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I am using C# and T-SQL.

I am trying to get the date of the most recent record from a table matching a specific condition, and I am stuck on the matching part. Currently what I have is:

```
date = (DateTime)(context.corresps.OrderByDescending(x => x.tevent).Select(x => x.tevent).FirstOrDefault());
```

What I am not able to figure out how to add to this statement is:

```
WHERE cmethod = 'W'
```

I could rewrite this as a standard LINQ query, but am trying to better myself. Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Im missing something:

`var date = context.corresps.OrderByDescending(x => x.tevent)
  .Where(x => x.cMethod == "W")
  .Select(x => x.tevent)
  .FirstOrDefault());`

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the whole concept.

when you have

```
context.corresps.OrderByDescending(x => x.tevent).FirstOrDefault()
```

you get a `corresp` that has the highest value for the field `tevent`

you can add a condition to your query by using where clause like this

```
context.corresps.Where(x => x.cmethod = 'W').OrderByDescending(x => x.tevent).FirstOrDefault()
```

and at the end you can not cast your `corresp` to `DateTime` unless you have implemented this feature inside `corresp` class. so you should get a date time you want from the object itself. final code is going to be something like this

```
var lastCorresp = context.corresps.Where(x => x.cmethod = 'W').OrderByDescending(x => x.tevent).Select(x => x.tevent).FirstOrDefault();
var lastDate = lastCorresp.tevent; //or any other field that represents the date time you want, since you've ordered your query by tevent field I assume that this field holds the date time you want to use
```